# String conversion to integer

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert this "9876543210223023" into integer which is received as a string .I have used parseInt but it gets converted into 9876543210223024.
This is causing failure in my validations .
Please suggest how will the value remain same after conversion.

Comment: Take a read to [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt). Maybe that could help you...

Comment: That number exceeds Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER so you cannot parse it as a precise integer. Do you need to perform arithmetic on it? (i.e. why does it need to b a number for validation)

Comment: @Shidersz `BigInt` isn't supported by Edge or Safari and in Firefox it's an experimental feature disabled by default, so that might not be a viable option for OP.

Comment: @AlexK. Yes.i need to perform comparison with other numbers

Comment: What type of comparisons? for equality just keep everything as strings.

Comment: Greater and Less than other fields which is an integer

Answer (score 1):

9876543210223023 is > than 9007199254740991, which is `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.

JavaScript has a Number type, which internally is a **64 bit floating point number**. 
If the range is too big, the machine episilon is too large, and the number is rounded to the nearest representable number, in this case 9876543210223024.

You need a [biginteger library](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js), if you want to process numbers of this size.
If your browser is modern enough (aka Chrome/Chromium), it might have the type "BigInteger" already built-in.

In that case: `BigInt("9876543210223023", 10)`
Otherwise, the linked BigInt-library will act as polyfill.

Comment: So if my string is of 15 digits,will it be parsed without any issues

Comment: @Divya G: If you use BigInt, as long as the number will fit into your computer's memory, you'll be fine. "BigInteger.js is an arbitrary-length integer library for Javascript, allowing arithmetic operations on integers of unlimited size, notwithstanding memory and time limitations."